# What is 'e' in 'e.preventDefault()'?

Tags: javascript, events

I am not able to understand the parameter 'e' which is passed to prevent the Default Action in JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', calculate, false);
function calculate(e){
  e.preventDefault():
}
```

Comment: e is the event.

Comment: e represents the event which has a lot of properties.

Comment: You can read about the [click event here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click)

Comment: When the JavaScript engine calls the callback you provided, it passes an `Event` object. You gain access to that passed object by giving the function a parameter. You don't have to call it `e`; you can use any valid variable name you want. Your confusion probably arises from the fact that you provide a function called by JS, instead of the other way around.

Answer (score 3):

The *e* in *e.preventDefault* prevents the default action when a link is clicked, which is the page refreshing or changing. So it allows for behavior such as clicking on a link making a call to the database without a page refresh.

Here is a guide on the topic: *[jQuery event.preventDefault() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp)*

Comment: No; *calling the `preventDefault` method* prevents the default action. The `e` itself *is the event object*. (Also, w3schools has a quite poor reputation as a reference.)

Answer (score 1):

The `Event` type is passed into the second argument of [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). This is referenced as `e` in the closure you've defined, and on which you've called [.preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

[MDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDN_Web_Docs) (in the links above) provides excellent documentation of the above type, the functions that you can call on it and the impacts those functions have.

Comment: No, the argument passed to `addEventListener` is the callback - not the event, and not the `Event` type. The callback here is implemented as an ordinary function, not as a closure. The event is passed *to the callback*.

Answer (score 1):

Where the code says

```
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', calculate, false);
```

This means that the function named `calculate` will be used to handle `'click'` events for the `'submit'` element in the `document`. That is: the Javascript engine makes a note to call `calculate` any time that the user clicks on the element with an ID of `'submit'`.

When that function is called, it will be passed [an object that *represents the event*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) - specifically, it will be a [mouse event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent), because clicking is done using the mouse.

So, where the code says

```
function calculate(e){
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

This `MouseEvent` object will be assigned to the parameter `e` used in the function's code. The name `e` is entirely arbitrary, just like any other function parameter. The object stores a lot of information about the event: for example, which buttons were clicked, whether modifier keys were pressed for the click, the location of the click (in multiple different coordinate systems), and whether it came from an actual mouse or from touching a touchscreen. It also provides the core `Event` functionality, such as a timestamp for exactly when the mouse was clicked.

For completeness:

Any time that the mouse is clicked in the browser normally, the browser itself will have its own rules for what should happen - for example, clicking on an ordinary `<a>` link tells the browser to go to the linked URL. This is the "default" action. The `Event` has a special method `preventDefault`: calling this method signals to the browser to *prevent* that default action - i.e., to *not* do whatever it was going to do otherwise.

This is useful so that, for example, a submit button on a form can do some validation in Javascript, and then **not submit** the form if there is something wrong with the form inputs.

Comment: I wrote a new answer because my attention was drawn to this question by the "Tyrannical Mods of Stack Overflow" video and the existing answers were full of technical inaccuracy. I have not used Javascript regularly in a very long time (although I am planning to get back into it) but this is pretty basic material.